# forEach error in ejs file when passing data to from database to ejs file

Tags: node.js, ejs

My data is stored in database with collection name "user" but when i try to fetch data from database and try to display with ejs . Sometimes it show me data not found or now it showing forEach is not a function.And even i installed all the necessary modules for this.

`Here is my app.js code`

```
app
  .route("/newCandidate")
  .get(function (req, res) {
    res.locals.title = "New Candidate";
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
      console.log("registration done!");
      res.render("newCandidate");
    } else {
      res.render("login");
    }
  })
  .post(function (req, res) {
    console.log("working candidate status");
   

    var {

      name,
      email,
      mobile,
      offerIssued,
      offerDate,
      offerDoc,
      packageOffered,
      joiningBonus,
      joiningDate,
      isVerified

    } = req.body;
    console.log(req.body);

    var data = req.body;
    var isVerified = true;

    User({
      name,
      email,
      mobile,
      offerIssued,
      offerDate,
      offerDoc,
      packageOffered,
      joiningBonus,
      joiningDate,
      isVerified,
    }).save((err,data) =>{
      if(err){
        console.log(err);
      }else{
        console.log(req.body);
        res.locals.title = "List Status";
        res.render("listStatus");
      }
      
    });
   
  });

  app.get("/listStatus",function (req, res) {
    var data = User(req.body).save(function(err,item){
      if(err)console.log(err);
      res.locals.title = "List Status";
      res.render("listStatus",{item:data});
    });
 });
```

`Here is my ejs file code`

```
  <% item.forEach(function(items){ %>
          <tr>
          <th scope="col"><%=items.name%></th>
          <th scope="col"><%=items.email%></th>
          <th scope="col"><%=items.mobile%></th>
          <th scope="col"><%=items.offerIssued%></th>
          <th scope="col"><%=items.offerDate%></th>
          <th scope="col"><%=items.offerDoc%></th>
          <th scope="col"><%=items.packageOffered%></th>
          <th scope="col"><%=items.joiningBonus%></th>
          <th scope="col"><%=items.joiningDate%></th>
          <tr>
      <%  }); %>
```

In this ejs file , i used item to store data and in js file where i created object and value for which it can take values from database.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your logic is completely off.

When you are calling `User.save` you are getting back a document that represents your user which you are calling `item`. Then in your callback you are sending back an object with key that is also called `item` and you are setting its value to `data` that is not defined.

Code in ejs is complaining that `forEach` is not a function because somehow you expect `item` passed to your template to be an array but instead it is `undefined`.

Even if you change it in your handler to

```
res.render("listStatus",{item: item});
```

which is probably what you want to do, you will still not be able to call `forEach` because `item` in this case would be a single user (the one that you have just saved), not an array of users.

If you want to save the user and then render all the user, you would need to first save the user, wait till it is saved and then make another call to your database to fetch all the users and send those to the template instead.

Something like

```
app.get("/listStatus", async function (req, res) {
    // omitting error handling for the sake of clarity
    
    await User(req.body).save();

    const users = await User.find({});

    return res.render("listStatus", { users });
}

// and in the ejs
<% users.forEach(function(user){ %>
    ...
```